# How to save special characters in database

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I'm using a MySQL database and inserting like this:

```
  try (Connection connection = DbConnector.connectToDb();
             PreparedStatement stm = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Country (name) VALUES (?)")) {
            stm.setString(1, name);
            if (stm.executeUpdate() > 0) {
                result = true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logStackTrace(e);
        }
```

Now when I insert: België it is saved in a weird way in the database the ë isn't saved. How can I solve this?

EDIT:

I just changed the table via:

```
ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

But still when I add a new one it isn't displayed correctly on the webpage.

Comment: use the correct encoding in your db, your sourcecode and your machine

Comment: What is the field type in your database? How have you validated that you've got the correct data just before the database call? How have you validated that it's not stored correctly? I'm not saying it's not a problem - but we're hard-pressed to help without more information.

Comment: Field type is a String. I validated via my webpage and mysqlworkbench.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is 2 points in the database to check in order to correctly set the UTF-8 charset.

**Database Level**

This is obtained by creating it :

```
CREATE DATABASE 'db' CHARACTER SET 'utf8';
```

**Table Level**

All of the tables need to be in UTF-8 also (which seems to be the case for you)

```
CREATE TABLE  `Table1` (
    [...]
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

The important part being **DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci**

Finally, if your code weren't handling utf8 correctly, you could have forced your JVM to use utf8 encoding by changing the settings by on startup :

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 [...]
```

or changing the environment variable

```
"**JAVA_TOOLS_OPTIONS**" to -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8"
```

or programmatically by using :

```
System.setProperty("file.encoding" , "UTF-8");
```

(this last one may not have the desire effect since the JVM caches value of default character encoding on startup)

Hope that helped.

Comment: Thanks, I just did this ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci; but still when I add a new one it isn't good displayed. Do i need to set a default or something?

Comment: Make sure that your page encoding is same and also check this http://balusc.blogspot.in/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html and this also https://coderwall.com/p/rvduyw/jdbc-inserting-unicode-utf-8-characters-into-mysql